# Cannot Read Property In Ionic

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework, authentication, credentials

Here is my error:

> Cannot Read Property of "username" of Undefined TypeError

Here is my HTML code that is giving me the error:

```
<ion-content  padding style="text-align: center; margin-top: 35px">
    <form (ngSubmit)="logForm()">
        <ion-list>

    <ion-item style="width: 80%; margin-left: 10%; margin-right: 10%">
      <ion-label fixed>Username</ion-label>
      <ion-input [(ngModel)]="cred.username" type="text" id="username"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
        <ion-list>

    <ion-item style="width: 80%; margin-left: 10%; margin-right: 10%">
        <ion-label fixed>Password</ion-label>
      <ion-input [(ngModel)]="cred.password" type="password" id="password"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
  <ion-list>

      <ion-item style="width: 80%; margin-left: 10%; margin-right: 10%">
          <ion-label fixed>Re-Type</ion-label>
        <ion-input [(ngModel)]="cred.passwordTwo" type="password" id="passwordTwo"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>

  <button style="width: 80%; height: 40px; margin-left: 10%; margin-right: 10%; margin-top: 10px"  (click) = "loginMain()" >Sign Up</button>
  <h5>Have An Account?</h5> <a style="color: blue;" (click) = "login()" > Log In! </a>
</form>
</ion-content>
```

I am trying to have the value of cred save cred.username and cred.password when you hit the Sign Up button. Instead, I just get this error. What is the Issue?

***EDIT***: When adding the question marks (cred?.username):

```
Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: The '?.' operator cannot be used in the assignment at column 17 in [creds?.username=$event]
```

Comment: can you post your ts code as well

Answer (score 0):

thats the elements are not defined.
You can simply define in the TS file of the component a cred interface with username and password fields,like:

```
interface cred {
    username?: string;
    password?: string;
}
```

Then you can use them in your HTML template